# Add Score on QC Checkbox List Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help me Master,

I'm trying to make the Quality Control checkbox and scoring system in Unity, what I want is when I enable the checkbox, the score is added by 1 point and has a total of 10 points.

Then when I hit a *"Test Report"* button it move to *"QC Pass"* screen (with 10 points) and move to *"QC No"* screen (less than 10 points), can anyone help me here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to listen for a toggle event from the checkbox and do any work when the value of the toggle event is true

```
void ToggleValueChanged(Toggle change)
{
    if(change.isOn)
    {
        // makred, increment your counter
    }
    else 
    {
        // unmarked, do whatever
    }
}
```

To get this event working, you can get a reference to the toggle button and register on `void Start()` make sure to attach this script on the gameObject of the toggle button or alternately, provide a reference manually

```
void Start()
{
    //Fetch the Toggle GameObject
    m_Toggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
    //Add listener for when the state of the Toggle changes, to take action
    m_Toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
        ToggleValueChanged(m_Toggle);
    });
}
```